# Force black navigation bar

Tags: emui, navigation-bar

The navigation bar at the bottom of my screen adapts with the app I'm using at any given time. This would be nice if it actually worked, but for some apps even while using dark theme the bar would turn into a bright white, which just looks distracting. I'd prefer to have it be all black at any given time, but I couldn't find any system settings for it. Is there a way to accomplish this using ADB or something?

I've got a Huawei Mate 20 X with EMUI 11.

Also here's an example screenshot of an otherwise dark app having a white navigation bar:

[image]